# Over heating H-bridge MOSFET (irf9540)?

Tags: dc, h-bridge

I have done the circuit in the picture :
[image]
from [here](http://letsmakerobots.com/content/yet-another-fet-based-h-bridge?page=1)

(modified  Question):

So two LEFT MOSFET (IRF9540 & IRF540) will be overcharged and so heating and  DC motor speed is constant and didn't change by difference pulses as ENABLE signal (PWM) from an IC555 (VBat = 12v) and (v-A or V_B=12v) 
so what do you think?!

I simulated this circuit in Proteus (combined with an IC555 for PWM and you could see its image:

[image]

You could get Sim file in :

http://filepi.com/i/BNIZOTG

Simulation works, but the value of the RV1 potentiometers doesn't change during the simulation and the motor speed doesn't change by changing the potentiometer value during the simulation. I have this problem too in the real board when I am changing the ic555 potentiometer the motor speed doesn't change and it is only constant at some specific speed!!! (there is no PWM pulse!!!)

Maybe if I change its biasing part it will work.

And I have another question:
What would be happened if I will drive a MOSFET with nominal Vgs (like 10V) and how no load in its drain .is it overheating!?
I think its don't work correctly in biasing of IRF540 MOSFETs. So could you help me to make it correct?

Comment: Please upload the sim file to a site that _doesn't_ try to run a suspicious .exe file on my computer!

Comment: uploaded in good server www.filepi.com

Comment: "delete" appears to be only option on that download page. Please make the file downloadable, or if you can't do that then make the screenshot big enough for us to read the schematic.

Comment: excuses me .done

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your Proteus simulation:-

1. The LOG pots you have chosen for RV1, RV2 and RV3 do not appear to work. After I switched RV1 to `POT-LIN`the 555 timer started generating a PWM signal.
2. Using 100k potentiometers to change direction is not appropriate. RV2 and RV3 should be changed to a DPDT switch or digital signals.
3. There is no connection between Q5 and Q3 or Q11 and Q10 (they only look connected because they are placed too close together). You need to move them apart, then add a wire from the Emitter of the upper transistor (Q5/Q11) to the Collector of the lower one (Q3/Q10).

Comment: thanks a lot . i am new to Proteus, so i have POT-LIN as my potentiometers first, but because i want to change theirs Resistance during simulation i changed them. when i done your advices i got sim error (too many simulation without convergence). you could see the modified Proteus file s here:  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=75218463373263894542

Comment: I don't know what's causing the convergence problem, but you only need to single step a few frames to see how the circuit works.